How to properly store DATE in APEX ORACLE with time included?
I am creating a specific app, where I need to set starting and ending times for orders. The problem rises with the DATE datatype format for storing, well, date.
The APEX ORACLE documentation states:

DATE is the oldest and most widely used data type. Though the name is "DATE", it stores also information about the time.

The issue I face is that, no matter how I try to store it, I can only retrieve the DATE without time (et. 05/10/2024 as MM/DD/YYYY), when looking manually in table 'data' or using a quarry.
The passed value is 10-MAY-2024 10:00 and it is converted via
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    toDate DATE;
    BEGIN
    toDate := TO_DATE(:START_PICKER, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI');
    INSERT INTO MISENE VALUES (toDate);
    END;
END;

When stored as DATE, it returns the before mentioned 05/10/2024.
When stored as TIMESTAMP, it returns 10-MAY-24 10.00.00.000000000 AM, which I can use, but it makes it difficult to work with, as I need to use 24 hour format.
When stored as a VARCHAR2, it returns 5/10/2024 .
If not using conversion TO_DATE or forcing the toDate DATE;, it either returns an error, stating that there are non numeric values, or in case of VARCHAR2, the original value (10-MAY-2024 10:00).
Desired result is that it is stored under DATE datatype with time included (24 hour format, if possible), as mentioned in the ORACLE documentation, so I can use it to find values that would not overlap with other order times.

"... I can only retrieve the DATE without time (et. 05/10/2024 as MM/DD/YYYY), when looking manually in table 'data' or using a quarry." - that sounds as if you have a problem with client tool you use to retrieve data. Check whether its default date format is set to MM/DD/YYYY. If so, change it to something more appropriate. Or, while retrieving data, use e.g. select TO_CHAR(date_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from ... and you should see time component as well.

BEGIN
    DECLARE
    toDate DATE;
    BEGIN
    toDate := TO_DATE(:START_PICKER, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI');
    INSERT INTO MISENE VALUES (toDate);
    END;
END;

appears correct but could be simplified to:
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MISENE (your_date_column)
    VALUES (TO_DATE(:START_PICKER, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'));
END;

(Note: it is considered good practice to name which columns you are inserting into.)

The issue I face is that, no matter how I try to store it, I can only retrieve the DATE without time (eg. 05/10/2024 as MM/DD/YYYY), when looking manually in table 'data' or using a query.

A DATE is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It ALWAYS has those 7 components and it is NEVER stored in any particular human-readable format.
Your problem is probably not storing the date (since your code appears correct, even if it could be simpler) but that the client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc.) is formatting the binary DATE data as a string when it displays it (so that what is displayed is meaningful to you, the user) and that implicit conversion is only showing the date component and not the time; that does not mean that the time component is not being stored - only that it is not being displayed.
You can use:
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS your_date_column
FROM   misene;

To explicitly display the date as a string in a specific format.
Or, modify the preferences for your client application to change how that client formats dates so that it also shows the time component.
In SQL*Plus and SQL Developer (and some others) that can be done by changing the NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

and then:
SELECT your_date_column FROM misene;

Should show both the date and time components for dates (in an ISO8601 format).
(For other client applications, consult their documentation to see how to change how it formats dates.)

If the time component is displayed as 00:00:00 then you can use:
SELECT DUMP(your_date_column) FROM misene;

To look at the stored byte values in the DATE; if the last three bytes are zeroes (and you are not expecting the time to be midnight) then there is a problem with either taking the user input or with the INSERT as the time component is not being stored.

The issue was resolved by blindly adding TO_DATE converted values into DATE datatype and trying to visually represent them in the calendar asset, which works! Does not answer the question on how to actually see them via SQL or data in table, but makes the app usable.

To properly store a date with time in Oracle APEX, you would typically use the DATE data type or, preferably, the TIMESTAMP data type, as it includes both date and time components. Here's how you can do it:
Using TIMESTAMP Data Type:
Create a Table:You can create a table with a column of type TIMESTAMP to store the date and time.
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
date_time_col TIMESTAMP );

Inserting Data: You can then insert data into this table using the appropriate date and time format.
INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, date_time_col)

VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-05-09 14:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

Does not conventionally work, as there is an issue with Format Mask (that is DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM which is the only applicable one for me). That means I need to do even more converting, which can be a hassle.

"... you would typically use the DATE data type or, preferably, the TIMESTAMP data type, as it includes both date and time components.". DATE also includes time component, so your statement smells wrong (as if you thought that DATE doesn't contain it).
